# Should this answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers

The question itself is a bit problematic, and has votes to close. But the user voted an answer the "best" answer. Then the answer was edited to say "Delete this answer now"

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/89351/32987

So, should the answer be deleted? Or just leave things alone?

Comment: In the future you can flag a question for deletion, and send it to the review queue: http://i.imgur.com/UdOFqZZ.png It's a built-in and generally smooth process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rolled back the answer to revision 1. Defacing answers is frowned upon.

I think it should still be deleted but that should be handled by the review queue.

I don't think that the accepted status of the answer should matter for voting to delete answers.

Answer (score 2):

It should be deleted. It was very low quality before it was defaced and should have been deleted then. Just because a user accepted it does not make it fit for the site.